# PHP: conditional output for last record in a resultset

Tags: php, mysql

I have some PHP script querying a mysql database and echoing out a piece of javascript. Everything is working perfectly, except after echoing the last row of the query, I don't want to echo a comma after the closing bracket. The result of the script should look something like this below, with the last line NOT ending with a comma.

```
        {title: 'title1', url: 'mp3:mp3-1', start: 660, duration: 398},
        {title: 'title2', url: 'mp3:mp3-2', start: 464, duration: 32},
        {title: 'title3', url: 'mp3:mp3-3', start: 2956, duration: 139},
        {title: 'title4', url: 'mp3:mp3-4', start: 653, duration: 62},
        {title: 'title5', url: 'mp3:mp3-5', start: 1816, duration: 74}
```

As my code is now, the last line gets a comma just like the lines before it, and it is breaking my resulting javascript code (in IE only of course!!). I'm assuming the answer has to do with counting the number of rows left and if it's greater then 1 echo one thing, and if it's equal to 1 echo something else, I'm just not sure how to translate that into PHP code. Thanks for your help.

The code for the loop goes like this:

```
<?php
    foreach($_SESSION['section_remember'] as $key =>$value)
    {   

    $sql = "SELECT `section`.`start`,`section`.`stop`,`section`.`title`,`daily_show`.`audio_file`
                FROM `section`
                INNER JOIN `daily_show`
                ON `section`.`daily_show_id` = `daily_show`.`id`
                WHERE `section`.`id` = $value";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);


    while ($query = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $id = $query['id'];
        $start = $query['start'];
        $stop = $query['stop'];
        $title = $query['title'];
        $audio =$query['audio_file'];
        $duration =$stop-$start;

        echo"{title: '",$title;
        echo"', ";
        echo"url: 'mp3:",$audio;
        echo"', ";
        echo"start: ",$start;
        echo", ";
        echo"duration: ",$duration;
        echo"}, ";              
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: If you show your code, we can help better... however a common hacky solution is to append all of this in a string, and at the end of the loop trim off the last character (the last comma.)

Comment: Can you post your current code? :)

Comment: Can you show us the code for the loop?

Comment: @Fosco - I like to push them all into an array, and then just do `implode(",\n", $array);`.

Comment: just make an array and use php's json_encode()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of keeping track of whether you are on the last row, you could just trim the trailing comma using `rtrim`. All of the [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)ming functions (trim, ltrim, rtrim) in PHP take a second parameter `$charlist` in which you can specify which characters to trim.

```
ob_start(); // use output buffering or append to a string variable
while ($query = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id = $query['id'];
    $start = $query['start'];
    $stop = $query['stop'];
    $title = $query['title'];
    $audio = $query['audio_file'];
    $duration = $stop-$start;

    printf('{"title":"%s", "url":"mp3:%s", "start":%d, "duration":%d},',
        $title,
        $audio,
        intval($start),
        intval($duration)
        );
}
echo rtrim(ob_get_clean(), ', ');
```

Comment: Really, this is the easiest solution to this exact issue. Who needs incrementing counters or imploding an array when you can just trim the last comma?

Comment: Great solution. Probably faster than evaluating a condition on every iteration too, especially so when the condition changes *only once* regardless of the input size. You have my upvote.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This sounds like a great solution, but my lack of skills leave me at a loss for how exactly to implement this into my code.

Comment: @JackBurton I modified my example to include your while-loop, which you now can replace by simply copy and paste.

Comment: @nikc works like a charm, thanks! Now I better go read the manual on output buffering....

Answer (score 2):

I think you're on the right track. Get the number of rows from that query. `for` every row, increment a counter that starts at zero. `if` the number of rows and the counter are not equal, print a line with a comma. `else`, print a line *without* a comma. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

The comma can be placed at the top of your loop instead of bottom; that way you know for sure that there is at least one row to go:

```
$count = 0;
while ($query = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $count++ > 0 ? "," : ""; // notice the use of post-increment operator
    echo"{";
    echo"}";              
}
```

Comment: Wrong. Echos ',' only on first line but not only on last.

Comment: Quite a clever idea to use the enterprise (http://enterprise-js.com/11) leading comma ;-)

Comment: @Grrbrr404: not sure but I've revised my answer.

Comment: Still the same error in my eyes. He wants , on each line instead of the last one. $count++ is 0 on first executen, so it echos ",". On every following loop run it echos "" / empty string

Comment: @Grrbrr404 No. It echoes ',' on all except the first row. But notice that it's a _leading_ comma, not a _trailing_ comma, so it works perfectly.

Comment: @GrrBrr404: I fail to understand why you say that. Please have a look at [this](http://www.ideone.com/o4FOU) and [this](http://www.ideone.com/TVfxq)

Comment: This is pretty clever, but maybe *too* clever. As we can see, it might be a little hard for some people to understand what's going on here (e.g. next guy who maintains the code). +1 all the same.

Answer (score 1):

Before your echo loop safe the mysql row count in a var. In your loop check your loop indicator ($i or whatever) and make a `if ($cout - 1 == $i)  {echo 'something else';}` instead of your usual echo.

Regards